# Am I misunderstanding how foreign keys work? Using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Let's say I have two tables.

Animals:

| animal_Id | name | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mouse | Yellow |
| 2 | Elephant | Green |
| 3 | Mouse | Red |
| 4 | Bear | Purple |

Zoo:

| cage_Id | size | animal_Id (foreign key) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Large | 2 |
| 2 | Small | 1 |
| 3 | Small | 3 |

Am I right in assuming that I could create code which would:

- Allow a user to view the Zoo.
- Select a small cage within it: **2**.
- Be told that the cage contains a **Mouse, yellow**.
- *Or* select an animal and place them in a cage (size) of their choice, which would result in a new 'Zoo' row:

| cage_Id | size | animal_Id (foreign key) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Large | 4 |

If yes, then to use this with Sequelize, I'd need a one-to-one relation right?
My code would basically look like:

```
db.cage = require("../models/cage.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.animal = require("../models/animal.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.cage.hasOne(db.animal);
db.animal.belongsTo(db.cage);
```

And I wouldn't have to go into the model and edit in the foreign key reference.

I tried `db.cage.hasMany(db.animal);` which absolutely didn't work. Trying to see if my current thinking is correct. Thanks!